# Angular adding CSS in devtolls works, but not in the code

Tags: css, angular

I need to make elipsis max length on multiline in CSS. So I just:

```
.body {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

But it doesnt work, however if I set this via Chrome devtools on the selected element (`element.style {}` ), it works.

Doesnt work:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhAIr.png)

Works:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WQCL.png)

As you can see, styles are added in both cases (only for some reason `-webkit-box-orient: vertical;` is not added in first one).

Any help?

Comment: please add relevant code

Comment: Are your styles scoped? Where do you add this `css`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autoprefixer removes outdated prefixes that are no longer needed. Try using this to ignore the removal of style.

```
.body {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
   /* autoprefixer: ignore next */
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

Comment: Well that is interesting. Now styles are applied and it works well. Could you please elaborate a bit more if possible? Is this can be considered as a good approach to my goal?

Comment: AutoPrefixer parse your CSS and add vendor prefixes to CSS rules. And as I mentioned this rule is already removed so it will not parsed through it.

Comment: Here, before this css statement comes we are making autoprefixer ignore or off. so that this style can render

Comment: Oh, just found that `line-clamp` support is not enough - f.ex. Firefox doesnt support it... Will look other solutions. But your answer is great! Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, It won't work in other browsers as line-clamp is only works with webkit. Let me know the solution if you get for all the browsers for line clamp